# Write all TreeView nodes to text file

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to save all `TreeNodes` with `Text="Group"` from my `TreeView` to a file. I'm able to print all `TreeNodes` with `Text="Group"` but when I add a `StreamWriter` plus a file name , the result is a blank file. I am sure there are one or more `TreeNodes` which name is Group, so that couldn't be the problem. How can I fix my code?

The result for the file can look like this for example

> Group 1
>
> Group 0

EDIT:

I found the fix I added `streamWriter.Close();` at the end of the `CreateSiveFile` method, now it works.

Code

```
    public void CreateSaveFile(string fileName ,TreeView treeView)
    {
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        // Print each node recursively.
        TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView.Nodes;
        foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
        {
            WriteRecursive(streamWriter, n);
        }
    }

    public void WriteRecursive(StreamWriter writer, TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        if (treeNode.Text == "Group")
        {
            writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", treeNode.Text, treeNode.Nodes.Count));
            // Print each node recursively.
            foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
            {
                WriteRecursive(writer,tn);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on finding the problem! If you don't mind, I'll point out a useful (and best practice) technique you can use on things like this going forward.

Because `StreamWriter` implements `IDisposable`, it's best to implement it with a `using` statement. And really with anything that implements `IDisposable`, you should either use `using` or call `.Dispose()` explicitly, to let the CLR know to free up its resources. It's not *just* a best practice, but in this case doing so would've solved the problem of the stream not closing, because when the `using` statement closes, it implicitly calls `streamWriter.Dispose()`, which implicitly calls `streamWriter.Close()`. (For readability, you can leave an explicit call to `streamWriter.Close()` in there if you like.)

Here's the recommended way, with `using`:

```
public void CreateSaveFile(string fileName, TreeView treeView)
{
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        // Print each node recursively.
        TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView.Nodes;
        foreach (TreeNode n in nodes)
        {
            WriteRecursive(streamWriter, n);
        }
        streamWriter.Close(); // Optional since we have "using", but good practice to include.
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about `using` statements, and I had it in there before, but thanks for the reminder